# Implement Mastercard Gateway Android SDK in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, payment, mastercard

I am trying to implement the Mastercard Gateway Android SDK in Xamarin.Forms but according to the documentation I need to edit the gradle.properties file which is not present in Xamarin.Forms. Is it possible for me to implement this SDK and if so how? What nuget packages do I need? I currently have the Com.MasterCard.Sdk, Com.Mastercard.Psp.Payment and MasterCard.Core packages I'm using Visual Studio 2019

EDIT: The payment gateway in question: https://github.com/Mastercard-Gateway/gateway-android-sdk

Comment: I just tried downloading the sdk as an aar file from mvn repository, made a binding library with it then implementing it inside the app projec. Now when I try to set the merchant id it gives me this error: Add a reference to assembly 'Mono.Android, version=-0.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'